Typescript err of not matching objects returned from reduce function and typed
Im getting the typescript error that the type of object returned from the function is not the same as typed (IData). I tried to research hat Im doing wrong but dont understand.

export interface IData {
  year?: number;
  days?: {
    day?: number;
    value?: number;
  }[];
}

  const convertToChartData = (data?: SomeData[]): IData[] => {
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
      return Object.entries(
        data.reduce(
          (
            acc: Record<
              number,
              { day: number; value: number | undefined }[]
            >,
            { from, value }
          ) => {
            const [y, d] = from?.split("-").map(Number) ?? [];
            if (!acc[y]) {
              acc[y] = [];
            }
            acc[y].push({ day: d, value });

            return acc;
          },
          {}
        )
      ).map(([year, days]) => ({ year, days }));
    } else return [];
  };

What I return from function:
[
  { year: '2020', days: [ { day: 1, value: 12 }, {day: 2, value: 1} ] },
  { year: '2021', days: [ day: 1, value: 132, {...}, ] }
]

EDIT:
the error in my editor shows:
{
  year: string;   
   days: {     
     day: number;     
     value: number | undefined;   
   }[]; 
}[]

is not assinable to IData

{   
  year: string;   
  days: {     
    day: number;     
    value: number | undefined;   
  }[]; 
}

Types of property year are incompatible.
Type string is not assignable to type number

EDIT:
the incoming data type:
interface SomeData {
  from: string;
  value: number
};


year is in your example data a string and in your interface not. could you please give the exact error message? normally it shows you what is missing.

I have edited my question with the type of error i see. Basically typescript says IData is an array of objects and returned data is not.

I think its maybe I need to specify the type for whats returned inside the reduce function AND AGAIN for returned data from the map function following the reduce function?!

@ThomasRenger actually I missed it in the end, it does say also that year is a string

I didnt thing the incoming data is relevant here, but updated my question with it.

You need to coerce keys back to numbers (because they are coerced to strings automatically by JavaScript) as shown in this playground link. Does that address your issue? If so I could write an answer explaining. If not, what's missing?

but even if in IData I and number to number | string | undefined, I still get the error. should it in this case go away?

I can't reproduce that. Please provide a [mre] of what you're talking about, otherwise it's impossible to help.
